# Xamarin android upload image to azure blob best approach?

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin, xamarin.android, azure-storage

Ive been trying a couple of things without success. Latest ive tried to use some code that works perfect when run on my desktop and given a true path to an image, however when a path is passed into the same method in Xamarin and on my android device, the selected image is not uploaded and there is no error.

Anyone who knows what the issue might be(wrong file path or something else entirely), or has another way to perform this task?

Here is the relevant code, the upper part is only used in my Xamarin project and i know the lower part works when i run it on my desktop with a path passed in manually.

// This part handles getting the image and its data from the phone, however the path of the image seems to be different than when i manually browse to the file.

```
    private void BtnClickFindImage(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Intent = new Intent();
        Intent.SetType("image/*");
        Intent.SetAction(Intent.ActionGetContent);
        StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(Intent, "Select Picture"), PickImageId);
    }
    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if ((requestCode == PickImageId) && (resultCode == Result.Ok) && (data != null))
        {
            Android.Net.Uri uri = data.Data;
            recipeImagePreview.SetImageURI(uri);

            var path = global::Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath;
            var fullPath = Path.Combine(path.ToString(), "IMG_20180701_105406608.jpg");
            Manager_AzureServer_RecipeImages.PushFilTilWebsite(fullPath);
        }
    }
```

// This part pushes the file to my Azure storage unit, it works like a charm when run from my desktop, however when run on my android device no file gets uploaded.  Either the path is not working, the code is not working on android for some reason or there could even be some kind of android rule that doesnt allow image upload from device by default

```
        public static void PushFilTilWebsite(string _imagePath)
    {       
        ProcessAsync(_imagePath);
    }

    private static async Task ProcessAsync(string _imagePath)
    {
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = null;
        CloudBlobContainer cloudBlobContainer = null;

        // Retrieve the connection string for use with the application. The storage connection string is stored
        // in an environment variable on the machine running the application called storageconnectionstring.
        // If the environment variable is created after the application is launched in a console or with Visual
        // Studio, the shell needs to be closed and reloaded to take the environment variable into account.
        // Encrypt den her før release.
        string storageConnectionString = "XXX";

        // Check whether the connection string can be parsed.
        if (CloudStorageAccount.TryParse(storageConnectionString, out storageAccount))
        {
            try
            {
                // Create the CloudBlobClient that represents the Blob storage endpoint for the storage account.
                CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

                // Create a container called 'quickstartblobs' and append a GUID value to it to make the name unique. 
                //cloudBlobContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference("quickstartblobs" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
                cloudBlobContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference("lghrecipeimages");

                // Set the permissions so the blobs are public. 
                BlobContainerPermissions permissions = new BlobContainerPermissions
                {
                    PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob
                };
                await cloudBlobContainer.SetPermissionsAsync(permissions);

                // Get a reference to the blob address, then upload the file to the blob.
                // Use the value of localFileName for the blob name.
                CloudBlockBlob cloudBlockBlob = cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("test image upload2");
                await cloudBlockBlob.UploadFromFileAsync(_imagePath);

                finishedPushingToServer = true;                
            }
            catch (StorageException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error returned from the service: {0}", ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
            }
        }
        else
        {
        }
        string test = "";
    }
```

Comment: please do NOT post code as an image!

Comment: The reason that i showed it with an image was so that i could draw lines to clearify the issue.

Comment: @user10094935 use comments in code to clarify issue please remove the image.

Comment: did you attach a debugger in both cases? and saw how paths are different ? Also is there a permission you need to have in Android app to allow for upload?

Comment: Use Debugger or fiddler to retrieve the detail message like imagepath.

Comment: fiddler won't give you the image path, it should however show the binary image data

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are not using the correct path to your image.

You get the Uri from the File Picker Intent, however you don't use that except for a preview. This Uri needs to be translated to the actual path in external storage.

```cs
private string GetFilePathFromUri(Android.Net.Uri uri)
{
    string[] column = { MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.Data };

    var cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(this, uri, column, null, null, null);
    ICursor cursor = cursorLoader.LoadInBackground() as ICursor;

    string filePath = null;

    if (cursor != null)
    {
        var columnIndex = cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.Data);
        cursor.MoveToFirst();
        filePath = cursor.GetString(columnIndex);
    }

    return filePath;
}
```

This will translate your Uri, which looks something like `content://media/images/external/1234` to a file path which looks like: `/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20180718_071002.jpg`

This file path you can hand over to the Azure Storage SDK for upload.

Comment: I tried this, filePath returns null. 
However i tried passing in the proper filepath directly and did a check to see if the file existed on the path, which it did, so the path should be good and not the problem it seems. However still, the file was not uploaded.. 
Im starting to think there is some security rule or some such on my phone that prevents the upload....
   fullPath="/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20180701_105406608.jpg";
                
     bool exists2 = File.Exists(fullPath);

                Manager_AzureServer_RecipeImages.PushFilTilWebsite(fullPath);

Comment: Did you request external storage permission?

Comment: No ill try that now i guess as im at a loss here

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Cheesebaron for point me in the right direction, i now got it to work! 
The problem was that i was missing a needed permission to use external storage on device. Below im posting the code that fixed it for me, short explanation: In case the app doesnt have permission to use the external storage, prompt a request for this permission, once accepted by the user, the external storage can be used.

Feel free to use below working code, cheers!

```
       private void BtnClickFindImage(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage) == (int)Permission.Granted)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, "We already have this permission!", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
        else
        {  
            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            alert.SetTitle("Permission needed!");
            alert.SetMessage("The pplication need special permission to continue");
            alert.SetPositiveButton("Request permission", (senderAlert, args) =>
            {
                RequestPermissions(PermissionsGroupLocation, RequestReadExternalStorageId);
            });

            alert.SetNegativeButton("Cancel", (senderAlert, args) =>
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, "Cancelled!", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            });

            Dialog dialog = alert.Create();
            dialog.Show();

            return;
        }

        Intent = new Intent();
        Intent.SetType("image/*");
        Intent.SetAction(Intent.ActionGetContent);
        StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(Intent, "Select Picture"), PickImageId);
    }

    #region RuntimePermissions

    async Task TryToGetPermissions()
    {
        if ((int)Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= 23) // Android 7.0 - API 24 er min mobil
        {
            await GetPermissionsAsync();
            return;
        }
    }
    const int RequestReadExternalStorageId = 0;

    readonly string[] PermissionsGroupLocation =
        {
                        //TODO add more permissions
                        Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage,
         };
    async Task GetPermissionsAsync()
    {
        const string permission = Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage;

        if (CheckSelfPermission(permission) == (int)Android.Content.PM.Permission.Granted)
        {
            //TODO change the message to show the permissions name
            Toast.MakeText(this, "Special permissions granted", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            return;
        }

        if (ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permission))
        {
            //set alert for executing the task
            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            alert.SetTitle("Permissions Needed");
            alert.SetMessage("The application need special permissions to continue");
            alert.SetPositiveButton("Request Permissions", (senderAlert, args) =>
            {
                RequestPermissions(PermissionsGroupLocation, RequestReadExternalStorageId);
            });

            alert.SetNegativeButton("Cancel", (senderAlert, args) =>
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, "Cancelled!", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            });

            Dialog dialog = alert.Create();
            dialog.Show();


            return;
        }

        RequestPermissions(PermissionsGroupLocation, RequestReadExternalStorageId);

    }
    public override async void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        switch (requestCode)
        {
            case RequestReadExternalStorageId:
                {
                    if (grantResults[0] == (int)Android.Content.PM.Permission.Granted)
                    {
                        Toast.MakeText(this, "Special permissions granted", ToastLength.Short).Show();

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Permission Denied :(
                        Toast.MakeText(this, "Special permissions denied", ToastLength.Short).Show();

                    }
                }
                break;
        }
        //base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
```